# Fault Code:SOAP-ENV:Server String:Fault in Fedex Rate Service Response

Tags: php, soap, fedex

```
require_once('modules/FedEx/RateAvailableServicesService_v18_php/library/fedex-common.php5');
                    $path_to_wsdl = PATH."modules/FedEx/RateAvailableServicesService_v18_php/RateService_v18.wsdl";
                    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
                    $client = new SoapClient($path_to_wsdl, array('trace' => 1)); // Refer to http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.soap.php for more information
                    $request['WebAuthenticationDetail'] = array(
                        //'ParentCredential' => array(
                            //'Key' => $this->getProperty('key'),
                            //'Password' => $this->getProperty('password')
                        //),
                        'UserCredential' => array(
                            'Key' => $this->getProperty('key'), 
                            'Password' => $this->getProperty('password')
                        )
                    ); 
                    $request['ClientDetail'] = array(
                        'AccountNumber' => $this->getProperty('shipaccount'), 
                        'MeterNumber' => $this->getProperty('meter')
                    );
                    $request['TransactionDetail'] = array('CustomerTransactionId' => ' *** Rate Available Services Request using PHP ***');
                    $request['Version'] = array(
                        'ServiceId' => 'crs', 
                        'Major' => '18', 
                        'Intermediate' => '0', 
                        'Minor' => '1'
                    );
                    $request['ReturnTransitAndCommit'] = true;
                    $request['RequestedShipment']['DropoffType'] = 'REGULAR_PICKUP'; // valid values REGULAR_PICKUP, REQUEST_COURIER, ...
                    $request['RequestedShipment']['ShipTimestamp'] = date('c');
                    // Service Type and Packaging Type are not passed in the request
                    $request['RequestedShipment']['ServiceType'] = 'INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY'; // valid values STANDARD_OVERNIGHT, PRIORITY_OVERNIGHT, FEDEX_GROUND, ...

                    $request['RequestedShipment']['Shipper'] = array(
                        'Address'=> array('StreetLines' => array($UL->str_add1,$UL->str_add2),'City' => $UL->city_name,'StateOrProvinceCode' => $UL->state_name,'PostalCode' => $UL->zipcode,'CountryCode' => $UL->country_code));

                $request['RequestedShipment']['Recipient'] = array(
                    'Address'=>array('StreetLines' => array($this->session->get('shipping_address1'),$this->session->get('shipping_address2')),'City' => $shipping_city,'StateOrProvinceCode' => $shipping_state,'PostalCode' => $this->session->get('shipping_postal_code'),'CountryCode' => $country_code,'Residential' => false));

                $request['RequestedShipment']['ShippingChargesPayment'] = array(
                    'PaymentType' => 'SENDER',
                    'Payor' => array(
                        'ResponsibleParty' => array(
                            'AccountNumber' => $this->getProperty('billaccount'),
                            'Contact' => null,
                            'Address' => array(
                                'CountryCode' => COUNTRY_CODE
                            )
                        )
                    )
                );          
                $request['RequestedShipment']['PackageCount'] = '1';
                $request['RequestedShipment']['RequestedPackageLineItems'] = array(
                    '0' => array(
                        'SequenceNumber' => 1,
                        'GroupPackageCount' => 1,
                        'Weight' => array(
                            'Value' => $UL->weight//,
                            //'Units' => 'LB'
                        ),
                        'Dimensions' => array(
                            'Length' => $UL->length,
                            'Width' => $UL->width,
                            'Height' => $UL->height//,
                            //'Units' => 'IN'
                        )
                    )
                );
                try {
                    if(setEndpoint('changeEndpoint')){
                        $newLocation = $client->__setLocation(setEndpoint('endpoint'));
                    }
                    $response = $client ->getRates($request);
                    if ($response -> HighestSeverity != 'FAILURE' && $response -> HighestSeverity != 'ERROR'){ 
                        echo 'Rates for following service type(s) were returned.'. Newline. Newline;
                        echo '<table border="1">';
                        echo '<tr><td>Service Type</td><td>Amount</td><td>Delivery Date</td>';
                        if(is_array($response -> RateReplyDetails)){
                            foreach ($response -> RateReplyDetails as $rateReply){
                                $this->printRateReplyDetails($rateReply);
                            }
                        }else{
                            $this->printRateReplyDetails($response -> RateReplyDetails);          
                        }
                        echo '</table>'. Newline;
                        printSuccess($client, $response);
                    }else{ 
                        printError($client, $response); 
                    }
                    writeToLog($client);    // Write to log file   
                } catch (SoapFault $exception) { 
                  printFault($exception, $client);   
                }
```

Here is error exception which i am getting

Fault

Code:SOAP-ENV:Server
String:Fault
Request

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://fedex.com/ws/rate/v18"><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:RateRequest><ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail><ns1:UserCredential><ns1:Key>AndJurrJfCvvWZWn</ns1:Key><ns1:Password>Rps8Pl4jF9zGp5wiEpDRhKiHo</ns1:Password></ns1:UserCredential></ns1:WebAuthenticationDetail><ns1:ClientDetail><ns1:AccountNumber>631140688</ns1:AccountNumber><ns1:MeterNumber>107714405</ns1:MeterNumber></ns1:ClientDetail><ns1:TransactionDetail><ns1:CustomerTransactionId> *** Rate Available Services Request using PHP ***</ns1:CustomerTransactionId></ns1:TransactionDetail><ns1:Version><ns1:ServiceId>crs</ns1:ServiceId><ns1:Major>18</ns1:Major><ns1:Intermediate>0</ns1:Intermediate><ns1:Minor>1</ns1:Minor></ns1:Version><ns1:ReturnTransitAndCommit>true</ns1:ReturnTransitAndCommit><ns1:RequestedShipment><ns1:ShipTimestamp>2016-03-30T18:35:41+05:30</ns1:ShipTimestamp><ns1:DropoffType>REGULAR_PICKUP</ns1:DropoffType><ns1:ServiceType>INTERNATIONAL_PRIORITY</ns1:ServiceType><ns1:Shipper><ns1:Address><ns1:StreetLines>SUITE 5A-1204</ns1:StreetLines><ns1:StreetLines>799 E DRAGRAM</ns1:StreetLines><ns1:City>TUCSON</ns1:City><ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>AZ</ns1:StateOrProvinceCode><ns1:PostalCode>94040</ns1:PostalCode><ns1:CountryCode>US</ns1:CountryCode></ns1:Address></ns1:Shipper><ns1:Recipient><ns1:Address><ns1:StreetLines>795 E</ns1:StreetLines><ns1:StreetLines>DRAGRAM</ns1:StreetLines><ns1:City>TUCSON</ns1:City><ns1:StateOrProvinceCode>AZ</ns1:StateOrProvinceCode><ns1:PostalCode>94040</ns1:PostalCode><ns1:CountryCode>US</ns1:CountryCode><ns1:Residential>false</ns1:Residential></ns1:Address></ns1:Recipient><ns1:ShippingChargesPayment><ns1:PaymentType>SENDER</ns1:PaymentType><ns1:Payor><ns1:ResponsibleParty><ns1:AccountNumber>631140688</ns1:AccountNumber><ns1:Address><ns1:CountryCode>KWI</ns1:CountryCode></ns1:Address></ns1:ResponsibleParty></ns1:Payor></ns1:ShippingChargesPayment><ns1:PackageCount>1</ns1:PackageCount><ns1:RequestedPackageLineItems><ns1:SequenceNumber>1</ns1:SequenceNumber>
<ns1:GroupPackageCount>1</ns1:GroupPackageCount><ns1:Weight>
<ns1:Value>20</ns1:Value></ns1:Weight><ns1:Dimensions>
<ns1:Length>8</ns1:Length><ns1:Width>10</ns1:Width>
<ns1:Height>10</ns1:Height></ns1:Dimensions></ns1:RequestedPackageLineItems>
</ns1:RequestedShipment></ns1:RateRequest></SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have trace on, you should look at the actual request/response data. When I took your raw POST data above (in which you shouldn't have posted your account/key info) I get back a schema validation error. Syntax looks correct but the country code for payor is KWI but should be US. I'd suggest you add some code to log the request and responses...

```
$soap_response_hdr = $client->__getLastResponseHeaders() ;
$soap_response = $client->__getLastResponse() ;
$soap_request_hdr = $client->__getLastRequestHeaders() ;
$soap_request = $client->__getLastRequest() ;
```

Comment: i have changes all the things but still same issue occur.

Comment: In Soap Response : SOAP-ENV:ServerFaultUnrecoverableClientErrorSchemaErrorvalidation failure for RateRequest Error:cvc-enumeration-valid: Value '1' is not facet-valid with respect to enumeration